# Can I get the same effect in flutter as the <TouchableOpacity /> in React Native?

Tags: react-native, flutter

I found that in React Native, when using  component, pressing the corresponding area can have a opacity effect.
In flutter, we sure can use InkWell widget, but i don't want a rectangle or square. Can we implement the same result using flutter. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Shan Liu you are correct that InkWell has its own "splash" effect which makes the rectangle or square you mentioned.

If you don't want that splash effect, use GestureDetector.

In below example, I put a Text inside a GestureDetector, but you can put your widget there instead:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'InkWell Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(title: title),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(child: MyButton()),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyButtonState createState() {
    return MyButtonState();
  }
}

class MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  bool isTappedDown = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
      },
      onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
        setState(() {
          isTappedDown = true;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (tapUpDetails) {
        setState(() {
          isTappedDown = false;
        });
      },
      child: Text(
        'Flat Button',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: isTappedDown ? Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's one way to go. Cheers mate.

Comment: updates - if you tap on the text but release somewhere else. it would cause some side effects

Answer (score 8):

Use the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TouchableOpacity extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function onTap;
  final Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 50);
  final double opacity = 0.5;

  TouchableOpacity({@required this.child, this.onTap});

  @override
  _TouchableOpacityState createState() => _TouchableOpacityState();
}

class _TouchableOpacityState extends State<TouchableOpacity> {
  bool isDown;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() => isDown = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => setState(() => isDown = true),
      onTapUp: (_) => setState(() => isDown = false),
      onTapCancel: () => setState(() => isDown = false),
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        child: widget.child,
        duration: widget.duration,
        opacity: isDown ? widget.opacity : 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
TouchableOpacity(
  child: ....
  onTap: () {....}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to combine a gesture detector and an opacity animation. I couldn't find a ready to use example. But here is the example for opacity animation.
[Flutter opacity animation](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a touchable class I created. (You could easily add transparency here)

```
class Touchable extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function() onPress;
  final double borderRadius;
  final double padding;

  const Touchable(
      {Key key, this.child, this.onPress, this.borderRadius, this.padding})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
              child: child,
            ),
            onTap: this.onPress),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```